# iTunes asks me to subscribe to iTunes Match again when I try to turn iTunes Match back on

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-match

I wanted to disable iTunes Match temporarily, so I selected Turn Off iTunes Match from the menu bar. Now when I try to select Turn On iTunes Match, iTunes shows me this screen:

[image]

How can I turn iTunes Match back on, or did I get unsubscribed from iTunes Match?

(The answer is really obvious, but it took me so long to figure it out that I'm documenting it here by answering myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that I had just been logged out of iTunes Store. After I logged back in, I was able to turn iTunes Match back on.